Running JavaFX app inside Docker container: failed to load driver: iris
I am struggling with making an old JavaFX (+ JFoenix) school project work inside a Docker container.
I made a multi-project Gradle build config (commons, server and client) that runs well with Java 21 directly on my computer (Manjaro 6.6.32 64-bits / Wayland / Intel Core 11th Gen i3-1115G4 x4), but not with the following Dockerfile for the client app :
FROM gradle:8-jdk21-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /home/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . .
RUN gradle build

FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/client/build/distributions/client.tar .
RUN tar -xf client.tar
ENTRYPOINT ["./client/bin/client"]

With the command docker build -t jfxclient . && docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro jfxclient.
I have already solved some issues by adding the following line in the last stage :
RUN apk add --no-cache libx11 libxxf86vm mesa-gl mesa-dri-gallium

And running sudo xhost +local:docker before to start the container.
Now, I am facing the following error at startup, and I have not been able to solve it:
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: iris
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003fe6, pid=7, tid=34
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.3+9 (21.0.3+9) (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.3+9 (21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libprism_es2.so+0x8a1a]  Java_com_sun_prism_es2_X11GLFactory_nInitialize+0x1fa
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h" (or dumping to /usr/app/core.7)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/app/hs_err_pid7.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)

Changing the entrypoint to ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"], I obtained the file /usr/app/hs_err_pid7.log, but it is pretty long, 1181 lines. Here are what I consider to be the most interesting parts:
Stack: [0x00007fad00684000,0x00007fad00784a90],  sp=0x00007fad00783600,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libprism_es2.so+0x8a1a]  Java_com_sun_prism_es2_X11GLFactory_nInitialize+0x1fa
j  com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.nInitialize([I)J+0 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.initialize(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLPixelFormat$Attributes;)Z+73 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>()V+52 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x00007fad53a64cc6
V  [libjvm.so+0x912765]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, JavaThread*)+0x2e5
V  [libjvm.so+0x8ea08d]  InstanceKlass::call_class_initializer(JavaThread*)+0x2ed
V  [libjvm.so+0x8eb173]  InstanceKlass::initialize_impl(JavaThread*)+0x6f3
V  [libjvm.so+0x9f105d]  find_class_from_class_loader(JNIEnv_*, Symbol*, unsigned char, Handle, Handle, unsigned char, JavaThread*)+0x7d
V  [libjvm.so+0x9f9d40]  JVM_FindClassFromCaller+0x110
C  [libjava.so+0xe4d7]  Java_java_lang_Class_forName0+0xd7
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+19 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+6 java.base@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline()Lcom/sun/prism/GraphicsPipeline;+183 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init()V+0 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+1 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Thread.runWith(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+5 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+19 java.base@21.0.3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x00007fad53a64cc6
V  [libjvm.so+0x912765]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, JavaThread*)+0x2e5
V  [libjvm.so+0x9140ab]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, Klass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaThread*)+0x1cb
V  [libjvm.so+0x9ee64a]  thread_entry(JavaThread*, JavaThread*)+0x8a
V  [libjvm.so+0x928ccf]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner() [clone .part.0]+0xaf
V  [libjvm.so+0xf82c98]  Thread::call_run()+0xa8
V  [libjvm.so+0xd0b23a]  thread_native_entry(Thread*)+0x12a
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.nInitialize([I)J+0 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.initialize(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/prism/es2/GLPixelFormat$Attributes;)Z+73 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>()V+52 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x00007fad53a64cc6
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;+19 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+6 java.base@21.0.3
j  com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline()Lcom/sun/prism/GraphicsPipeline;+183 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init()V+0 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run()V+1 javafx.graphics@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Thread.runWith(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+5 java.base@21.0.3
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+19 java.base@21.0.3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x00007fad53a64cc6

Internal exceptions (7 events):
Event: 0.098 Thread 0x00007fad616eb890 Implicit null exception at 0x00007fad540049e3 to 0x00007fad54004b40
Event: 0.100 Thread 0x00007fad616eb890 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError'{0x000000008f2e7dc8}: 'void java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'> (0x000000008f2e7dc8) 
thrown [src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 772]
[...]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: --module-path=/usr/app/client/lib/client.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/commun.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/jfoenix-9.0.10.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/javafx-fxml-21.0.3-linux.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/javafx-controls-21.0.3-linux.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/javafx-graphics-21.0.3-linux.jar:/usr/app/client/lib/javafx-base-21.0.3-linux.jar -Djdk.module.main=application.client 
java_command: application.client/application.client.Main
java_class_path (initial): \"\"
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags foldmultilines=false
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags foldmultilines=false

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk
PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/lib/server:/opt/java/openjdk/lib:/opt/java/openjdk/../lib
DISPLAY=:0
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=xterm

I have installed mesa-demos package and been successful to run glxgears inside the container. It still prints the following message though:
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: iris

Here is some info provided by glxinfo:
name of display: :0
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: iris
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4

OpenGL vendor string: Mesa
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.3.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50

eglinfo has more info:
GBM platform:
eglinfo: eglInitialize failed

Wayland platform:
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
eglinfo: eglInitialize failed

X11 platform:
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
MESA: error: ZINK: vkCreateInstance failed (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
EGL API version: 1.5
EGL vendor string: Mesa Project
EGL version string: 1.5
EGL client APIs: OpenGL OpenGL_ES 
EGL driver name: swrast

I have tried many suggestions found on SO or elsewhere, but none did work so far.
I am now completely lost here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You have obviously done a lot of work here.  But why?  Why attempt to run a JavaFX application in a Docker container?

There is no real reason, mainly for the sake of the exercise. I am pretty convinced I am not so far from the solution...

"I am pretty convinced I am not so far from the solution" -> I think you are likely correct, though this is not something I have ever tried.  Best of luck with it.

There are a couple of things you might wish to try if you haven't already.  You could try Monocle: "Monocle is the implementation of the Glass windowing component of JavaFX for embedded systems. Monocle provides windowing functionality and access to native graphics for simple embedded systems that do not have an underlying window system."  They can be accessed from Maven for JavaFX 21. via classifier linux-aarch64-monocle (I believe though I have never tried).  That might reduce the system dependencies.

You could configure JavaFX to use software rendering -> -Dprism.order=sw and turn on verbose logging for the renderer -Dprism.verbose=true.  That would remove a dependency on opengl/hardware accelerated rendering/advanced graphics drivers.

Re, it's been a long time (7 weeks) I have not worked on it. I just resumed it yesterday and succeeded to make it work with -Dprism.order=sw. I have posted a full answer to explain the last steps to finish. Thank you very much for this advice.

I resumed it just today and I got it.
From within the container with entrypoint /bin/sh, I modified the client/bin/client shell script to add the -Dprism.order=sw -Dprism.verbose=true options in DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="", as recommended by user jewelsea. (Actually, I could have just executed export JAVA_OPTS="-Dprism.order=sw" before running the script to achieve the same result, so that's what I have done after.)
The first line when running the script changed from Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw to [...]: sw.
A new error log told me about ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory and java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glassgtk3 in java.library.path. I have also installed libc6-compat to fix it.
Then, finally, the app launched successfully. So far so good! Thanks to @jewelsea for the tip to finish this.
Final Dockerfile, run command and Docker Compose
FROM gradle:8-jdk21-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /home/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . .
RUN gradle build

FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jre-alpine AS client
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN apk upgrade --no-cache && apk add --no-cache gtk+3.0 libc6-compat libcanberra-gtk3
# no more mesa packages required with sw, but I added libcanberra to fix a warning
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/client/build/distributions/client.tar .
RUN tar -xf client.tar
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dprism.order=sw"
ENTRYPOINT ["./client/bin/client"]

sudo xhost +local:docker
# Reverse command: sudo xhost -local:docker
docker build -t client . && docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -e NO_AT_BRIDGE=1 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro --net=host --name client client
# $DISPLAY contains `:0`

services:
  client:
    build:
      target: client
    environment:
      DISPLAY: $DISPLAY
      NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1  # to ignore some warnings raised by GTK
    network_mode: host
    ports: []
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro

Other clues I found while doing research, but that did not fixed anything or not even tried:

Using JVM options -Djdk.gtk.version=3 -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true
Adding env variable -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.docker.xauth
Using volumes -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri:ro or -v /tmp/.docker.xauth:/tmp/.docker.xauth:ro
Using --platform linux/x86_64 (not tried)
Monocle (not tried)

